# Better way to say "responsible for official public written communication"

Tags: phrase-requests, writing, correspondence

I'd like to mention in my resume that I was responsible for official public written communication in my project, to show skills in communication, language and responsibility. What would be a good way to put it? Can the word "responsible" be avoided (I already use it in the previous sentence)?

I came across "executed communication", but that sounds crude.

Does "cultivated written official communication" sound good?

Comment: ‘Executed communication’ sounds like you had the communication stand facing a wall and then shot it in the head. Can you not just say that you managed or oversaw external communication?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet totally agree, but here's the source: http://www.ttparliament.org/documents/2135.pdf , and this is coming from a "Corporate Communications Department", no less. "Managed" sounds nice, thanks!

Comment: A corporate communications department sounds like an excellent place to go for absolutely terrible, obfuscatory writing filled with corporate mumbo-jumbo and utterly devoid of meaning. ;-)

Comment: I'd say _official written public communication_.

Comment: What organization or group were you writing for? If appropriate, perhaps a public relations writer, or internal communications writer would be more specific and indicate the nature of what you were writing.

Comment: '... with the remit to write official, public statements.'

Comment: *public and official communication in written form*.

Answer (score 2):

The source shows clearly that the employer desperately needs someone who can improve the quality of its communications. You would show that you are that person by writing in **very plain English** what you have done and by avoiding, like the plague, the overblown, abstract, management-speak as seen in the job description. "In my project, it was my job to tell people what we were doing..." - and even that is not good because there are a few words with more than one syllable, but I hope that might give you the idea.

Answer (score 0):

You could use **in charge of** or **my task was to**, some examples (the sentences are all a bit different to show that there isn't just one option):

> I was in charge of communication during my previous project.
>
> It was my task to communicate with third parties.

If you want the emphasis to be on *communication*, it [might be better to end you sentence with that](https://www.utdallas.edu/studentsuccess/files/Sentence-Emphasis.pdf), like this:

> During my previous project, I was in charge of communication.
>
> I was tasked public relations.